# How to iterate through list of lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell

What I am trying to do is make a program that will go through a two dimensional
square of numbers and find the path that gives the highest total. Starting from the 
top, valid moves are down, and down left/right if available.

The problem that I am having is I am using this function:

```
  slice :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
  slice x i k 
    | i > k = []
    | otherwise = (take (k-i+1) (drop (i-1) x))
```

and this function:

```
    path :: Board -> [Int]
    path [] = []
    path (x:xs) = (maximum (slice x 3 5 ) : path xs
```

where a type Board is a list of lists.

Could anyone explain to me how I could use variables instead of the 3 and 5, this way
I could get all the combos, and then evaluate which is the best route.

Comment: there is a great tool `hlint` that helps with indentation and ()-errors - `cabal install hlint`

Answer (score 1):

Newbie's first attempt :-)

```
path::[Board] -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
path [] y z = []
path (x:xs) y z = maximum(slice x y z) : path xs y z
```

Comment: thank you.. Now I'm trying to find the width of the square and make the function cycle through all the possible moves.  I need something like a loop, that'll go 1-3, 2-4 ect.

Comment: in haskell you rather use recursion or fold/scan for iteration than loops

Comment: yeah, im just having trouble finding the right recursive function.

Comment: @user1204349 - I suggest in that case to start a different thread with that question. And remember to accept the answer if it satisfies your question. Don't overload threads ;-)